# Help on understanding Schwartz space

Tags: harmonic-analysis

Can someone give an example of Schwartz space function that doesn't decay exponentially?

Comment: What do you mean by exponential decay?

Comment: I mean that it is not exponentially small at infinity. That is I need a function f in Schwartz space st for all a>0, e^(a|x|^a)f doesn't belong to L^infty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider your favorite bump function construction and replace the exponential function by $$e(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{\sqrt{k!}}$$